# How can I see the size of a partition's unallocated size on the command line after shrinking a partition with resize2fs?

Tags: shell, partition, fdisk, parted, resize2fs

I want to shrink my `/dev/sda2` partition from 463.37GB to 400GB to make room for a new partition.

So I did `e2fsck -f /dev/sda2` followed by `resize2fs /dev/sda2 400G`.

As per `man resize2fs`, *the resize2fs program does not manipulate the size of partitions.*, so the size is still 463.37GB.

When I start `GParted`, I can see the unallocated space:

[image]

13.27 GB Used + 386.73 GB Unused space totals 400 GB, as per my `resize2fs` command. Also, they grey area displayed is the unallocated space into which I'd like to create the new partition.

So far so good.

Yet, I'd like to see the size of the unallocated space *without* any GUI tool, only with command line tools such `parted`, `fdisk`, `df` or whatever. Unfortunately, I can't find how I can do that.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: You only took care of the fs. Now you have to boot from a DVD/pen and shrink the actual partition; with fdisk you have to actually delete it, and recreate it again with 401GB, just to be safe; you might be able to shrink it with parted, not sure about that. Then I would prefer to delete also the swap space, and recreate it again just to organize things around.

Answer (score 1):

`df` is already not that bad. `df` doesn't show the size of the partition, but the size of the filesystem itself. However, what it shows is also the *available* space, it does not reflect overhead, metadata and such.

For an exact value, you need more filesystem specific tools; for example `tune2fs -l /dev/device` should give you `block count`, `block size` and that should reflect your `400G` setting.

But since you already know it's `400G` you can just resize the partition to `400G` directly, just make sure not to use `400GB` instead of `400GiB` by accident...

Also if there are storage layers in between (mdadm, cryptsetup, ...), they add their own metadata and offsets which you have to take into account.